# After upgrading to Meteor 1.2 it still reports I have packages that were not upgraded

Tags: meteor

I just successfully upgraded to Meteor 1.2

But after upgrading I got this

```
The following top-level dependencies were not updated to the very latest version available:
 * kevohagan:sweetalert 0.5.0 (1.0.0 is available)
 * natestrauser:filepicker-plus 1.2.3 (2.0.0 is available)
 * natestrauser:select2 3.5.1 (4.0.0_1 is available)
 * zimme:iron-router-active 1.0.4 (2.0.1 is available)

Newer versions of the following indirect dependencies are available:
 * babrahams:editable-json 0.4.3 (0.6.0 is available)
 * matb33:collection-hooks 0.7.15 (0.8.0 is available)
 * meteorhacks:aggregate 1.2.1 (1.3.0 is available)
 * meteortoys:hotreload 0.2.0 (0.3.0 is available)
 * meteortoys:listen 0.3.0 (0.4.0 is available)
 * meteortoys:pub 0.3.1 (0.4.0 is available)  
 * meteortoys:status 0.1.0 (0.2.0 is available)
 * meteortoys:toypro 0.4.2 (0.5.0 is available)
 * softwarerero:accounts-t9n 1.0.9 (1.1.4 is available)
 * tap:i18n 1.5.1 (1.6.1 is available)        
 * underscorestring:underscore.string 3.0.3_1 (3.2.2 is available)
```

If I type `meteor update` I get the same thing. Am I supposed to upgrade each package manually? Why is Meteor not upgrading these automatically for me?

Comment: do you actually get errors? this seems more informational

Comment: No errors. And my server works. But what is this information for? Why didn't meteor update the packages it reports are behind?

Comment: I take it you already saw this? https://forums.meteor.com/t/1-2-upgrade-some-packages-not-upgrading-how-to-resolve/10160 Seems to suggest you do need to upgrade manually

Comment: Anecdata, but hey: After the upgrade, many of my packages would fail to install. `rm -rf ~/.meteor` and reinstalling fixed it for me. I'm on OS X.